# finding the sequence of functions executed when interacting with a contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, bsc, binance

I have interacted with a contract on BSC Blockchain and know I want to know the sequence of functions executed with my transaction. I got my hands on transaction GETH traces using BSCscan but that doesn't really tell me anything. I know I can check the code but is there any other way?

Comment: Hi cyberlobster! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Do you want the contract's transaction history?

Comment: @Ismael No I want to know which functions are called when I interacted with the contract (called a certain function on the contract). I know I can look at the code and figure it out but I guess there must be some other way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tools like https://dashboard.tenderly.co/ that allows tracing contracts that have source code verified.

For example this transaction on BSC https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc/0xb15663adf836fd5104c40d7cde9c27f1e4357440c642ab7451a225649ef10f11

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful tool for debugging transactions is Contract Library, and this one works irrespective whether the service has verified sources or not.

There are two main debugging views, transactions executed by contract a view which is [similar to a log](https://library.dedaub.com/contracts/Ethereum/A0B86991C6218B36C1D19D4A2E9EB0CE3606EB48/transactions).

You can also debug [individual transactions](https://library.dedaub.com/transactions/Ethereum/68B8E4161B8F5EE2F2A23A92C20A8E75EBE31C37691032F0ECA194F0A1A15FF1) on chain, or by connecting to your local node.